# Colors Change To Music?

Tags: animation

I know how to bake sound to F-Curves and stuff but how do I do that with colors? Like, can I have a material that becomes lighter when the music changes?

Comment: elaborate on what you mean by "When the music changes", it will help answer the question

Comment: Trombone to piccolo I assume?

Answer (score 1):

You can keyframe colour values the same as any other value, the catch is it will only keyframe the rgb values, not hsv.

To keyframe a colour either press <kbd>I</kbd> with the cursor over the colour or right-click <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> and select `Insert Keyframe`.

While you can then bake a sound into any of the keyed colour channels, it will be an erratic change, not a smooth fade that you most likely want, so you will want to manually key the fade that you want at the right time.